# sklearn can't find lapack in new conda environment

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, lapack

##### Question:

Why can't sklearn detect its liblapack dependency and how do I fix this?

##### Background:

I the following conda environment (`torch-nightly`) with `scikit-learn` installed (note that the `liblapack` dependency also exists):

```
(torch-nightly) au@a2 ~ % conda list |grep "scikit-learn"
scikit-learn              1.1.1            py38hc377ac9_0  
(torch-nightly) au@a2 ~ % conda list |grep "liblapack"
liblapack                 3.9.0           15_osxarm64_openblas    conda-forge
```

##### Problem:

I get the following error when attempting to import `sklearn`:

```
(torch-nightly) au@a2 ~ % python -c "import sklearn"                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 283, in <module>
    from . import csgraph
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/__init__.py", line 182, in <module>
    from ._laplacian import laplacian
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_laplacian.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from ._isolve import *
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/iterative.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/_iterative.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '@rpath/liblapack.3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/_iterative.cpython-38-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/../../../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_isolve/../../../../../../liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/au/miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file)
```

##### Research on Problem:

I confirmed that the "missing" library (`liblapack.3.dylib`) actually exists at the location shown in the error:

```
(torch-nightly) au@a2 ~ % ls miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/liblapack.3.dylib
miniconda3/envs/torch-nightly/lib/liblapack.3.dylib
```

Comment: There could be some inconsistencies among package dependencies in your environment because of different installations. Options to consider: running `conda update --force-reinstall scikit-learn` and running `conda update --all` within your environment.

Comment: Thank you @AlexK. Your suggestion solved my problem. I first uninstalled all numpy versions in my virtual environment. I reinstalled numpy==1.21.1 instead of the latest version.

After then, I  ran the two commands **conda update --force-reinstall scikit-learn** and **conda update --all**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: This answer is for `macOS` users only, and involves copying dilyb(s) that may not be compatible all versions of sklearn.
I highly recommend trying to re-install the packages first.
If you continue to fail and have reached a point where you are willing to try anything, the following steps may resolve the issue.

I was able to resolve this by manually copying over a copy of the necessary `dylib`(s) out of a homebrew installation.
First: I ran `brew install lapack`
[NOTE: For me, this installed version (3.11), you may end up with a different version after running the command]
Then I identified all the relevant files in of `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/lapack/3.11/lib/*`:

```
liblapacke.dylib
libblas.3.11.0.dylib
libblas.3.dylib
libblas.dylib
liblapack.3.11.0.dylib
liblapack.3.dylib
liblapack.dylib
liblapacke.3.11.0.dylib
liblapacke.3.dylib
```

Identify a search path that I all my python packages would search.
I'm using miniconda for my python environment management, for me it was: `~/miniconda3/envs/maxEnt/lib/`.

Step 1:
Delete all existing files with a matching name in this `lib` folder.

Step 2:
Copy the files referenced above.

Step 3:
Update all the symlinks (aliases) in these files [`.dylib` points to 3.11.0.dylib; `.3.dylib` points to `3.11.0.dylib`].

Answer (score 0):

for me, `conda install lapack` `conda install scipy` did the trick (OSX, M2 chip)